# How to limit textures size in eevee?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I'm using 2.8 beta. The option in the settings / general does not seem to work.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Hi, maybe try adding some more details, what you tried, what happened (or not), even better a visual example (screenshot) to let others know what you mean exactly

Comment: Just changed options. Nothing, same high res textures. Added screenshot.